# SQL Server 2008 trigger to HTML5 UI when table updated

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

Anybody got some advise on how I should tell my HTML5/JScript/jQuery UI that a table has been updated after a button has triggered a large stored procedure in my SQL Server 2008 database which can take up to 1 minute to complete.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would look at utilizing service broker with External Activator or SqlNotifications that would enable your application to know when there were changes in the underlying schema without having to poll changes.

External Activation [Link](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3927171/SQL-Server-Service-Broker---External-Activation.htm)

SqlNotification [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx)